# In Jenkins post how do I check, if the folder contents is blank

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

In Jenkins `post` stage how do I check, if the folder is blank/null, echo do nothing else delete the contents in the directory ?

```
post {
        always {
            
        script{
        if ("${env.BUILD_NUMBER}/**/*" == null)
        {
            echo "Nothing to delete"
        } else {
            archiveArtifacts artifacts: "${env.BUILD_NUMBER}/**/*", allowEmptyArchive: true, fingerprint: true
            sh "sudo rm -Rf ${SCREENSHOT_DIR}"
            
          }
          
        }
   }
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like,

```
post {
        always { script {
            dir =  sh(script: "ls -A ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}/", returnStdout: true).trim()
            if (dir.isEmpty()){
                echo "Nothing to delete"
            } else {
                echo "something"
            }
        }}
    }
```

Comment: Thank you !  I have tried above, but still getting an error in post condition:
`+ ls -A 19/
ls: cannot access '19/': No such file or directory
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
Error when executing always post condition:
hudson.AbortException: script returned exit code 2
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.DurableTaskStep$Execution.handleExit(DurableTaskStep.java:664)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.DurableTaskStep$Execution.check(DurableTaskStep.java:610)
 at`

Comment: It depends on where exactly you have to check. If your directory exists on your current WORKSPACE in the salve, the above code would work. Did you try checking if the directory really exists in the WORKSPACE? may try listing the directory when the job runs!